# How to have a namespace with action in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2, nested-routes

Below I have given the code of routes.rb:

```
  resources :analytics

  namespace :analytics do
    resources :users, only: [:show, :index]
  end
```

Here, I am having an analytics_controller.rb inside the controllers folder and one Analytics folder inside the Controllers folder which is containing this users_controller.rb

So whenever I want to go to http://localhost:3005/analytics/users to access the users_controller's index, it just sends me to analytics_controller's show action as it take the "users" as an :id in the above url.

What should I do? I want to keep both, all the actions of analytics_controller and also the actions of users_controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes have priority in the order they are defined. So if you want `/analytics/users` to be handled by users#index you need to define that route first.

```
namespace :analytics do
  get 'users', to: "users#index"
end

resources :analytics
```

You also don't seem to understand how [nested routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) work. Using resources to define nested routes would give `analytics/:analytic_id/users` as the index.

```
resources :analytics, only: [] do
  resources :users, only: [:index]
 end
```

---

```
        Prefix Verb URI Pattern                             Controller#Action
analytic_users GET  /analytics/:analytic_id/users(.:format) users#index
```

But this is not a very restful way to setup the routes in the first place. I would suggest:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :users do
    get :analytics, to: 'analytics#all'
  end

  resources :users, only: [] do
    resources :analytics, module: :users, only: [:index]
  end
end
```

Which would give the following routes:

```
         Prefix Verb URI Pattern                         Controller#Action
users_analytics GET  /users/analytics(.:format)          users/analytics#all
 user_analytics GET  /users/:user_id/analytics(.:format) users/analytics#index
```

The main difference here is that the routes clearly communicate that the resource being represented is analytics that belong to a user or the collection.

Using the `module` option sends the "nested" routes to `Users::AnalyticsController` and is a very good way to differentiate between different contexts.

```
class Users::AnalyticsController
  # Display all analytics for all users
  # GET /users/analytics
  def all
    @users = User.all
    @analytics = Analytic.where(user: @users)
  end

  # Display all analytics for a user
  # GET /users/:user_id/analytics
  def index
    @user = User.includes(:analytics).find(params[:user_id])
    @analytics = @user.analytics
  end
end
```

Comment: The route `"/users/analytics"` is unconventional. Its pretty rare that you display the nested records for an entire collection but if you really want to do it this is how.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the router to match the analytics/users path first you need to put the namespace before the resource :

```
namespace :analytics do
  resources :users, only: [:show, :index]
end
resources :analytics
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the routes that are going to generate with

```
localhost:3000/rails/info/routes
```

Then must be users_controller must be namespace with inside the controller/analytics/users_controller.rb

```
class Analytics::UsersControllers < ApplicationController
end
```

And the path for UserController action should be

```
analytics_users_path & analytics_users_path(user_id)
```